# Haskell list construction

Tags: haskell

Can somebody please explain what this function does in "otherwise" guard?

```
getWord :: String -> String
getWord [] = []
getWord (x:xs)
  | elem x spaces = []
  | otherwise = x: getWord xs
```

I don't realy get it what happens to x?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:` is the list constructor:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Eg:

```
λ> 1 : [1,2,3]
[1,1,2,3]
λ> 'h' : "ello"
"hello"
```

In that expression, `x : getWord xs` simply creates a list starting with `x`, and ending with `getWord xs`, which causes the recursion here.

Answer (score 1):

`otherwise` is just `True` (see [Prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:otherwise)).

`getWord` pattern-matches on a string, which is a list of characters, and if `x` is not a space character then it will keep adding (consing) characters until it reaches a space or the end of the string i.e. it will return the first word in a sentence.